# Using sObject.get() to fetch a field value from a related parent object

Tags: apex, sobject

I have a contact in a generic sObject in apex and while I'm able to easily get detail field values using

`sObject.get('MyContactField__c')`

I'm not able to get fields off the related parent object, and I'm sure the related field is in memory, based on the debug logs. This returns a runtime error:

`sObject.get('Account.MyAccountField__c')`

with the error

> Invalid field Account.MyAccountField__c' for Contact

How do I get a field value off of a parent on a generic sObject?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You need `getSobject()` to traverse relationship "up" in a dynamic way.

```
sObject acc = [SELECT Owner.Profile.Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];
String profileName = (String) acc.getSobject('Owner').getSobject('Profile').get('Name');
System.debug(profileName);
```

Check all dynamic `get*` methods in the [Sobject instance methods docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

Comment: As an added bonus, you can also use getsObjects() to go the other way down the tree: e.g.
    List<sObject> so = [Select Id, (Select Id from Contacts) from Account LIMIT 10];
    List<Contact> cons = so[0].getSObjects('Contacts');

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC yep, that's why I pointed to all "get" methods! :)

Comment: Just took me a while to realize that the phrase 'Returns the values for the specified field.' meant I could also get back the whole list...think the docs could use some additional detail...!

Comment: In case it helps someone else (I was wondering this):  Using the '__r' will work.  So if your dynamic code has something like List<sObject> sList = [Select Name, Custom__r.Name from Contact];  it can be addressed with sList[0].getSobject('Custom__r').get('Name');

Comment: The link was dead - edited.

Comment: Probably would be worth adding checks for a null parent if you were going to genericize this functionality. I guess in this case though neither parent is nillable.

Comment: @AdrianLarson how do we check for fields that does not have value for example , in my case `(String)obj.getSObject('Account').get('Name')` sometime does not have value and apex is throwing an error in that case to counter this  I have applied `obj.getSObject('Account') !=null ` check but seems not working at all

Comment: You should consider asking that as its own question @Hunt

Comment: @Hunt null check works for me, definitely post new question? `sObject o = [SELECT Manager.Name FROM User LIMIT 1];
sObject manager = o.getSobject('Manager');
String name = manager != null ? (String) manager.get('Name') : 'Nope';
System.debug(name);`. You could also `SELECT ManagerId` and check that... for related lists - I think list will always be there (never null value) but it's perfectly OK for it to be `isEmpty()`.

Comment: For null checks, using the save navigation operator should do the trick: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm