# Get Schema.SObjectField from Schema.FieldSetMember

Tags: apex, fieldsets, schema

I couldn't find any elegant (no use of Strings) to create a `Schema.SObjectField` from a `Schema.FieldSetMember`.

Can you think of one?!

The reason for asking this is that I was also unable to get the value of an SObject field dynamic by using:

```
SObject record = ...

for(Schema.FieldSetMember field : ...) {
   // Fails to compile
   record.get(field);

   // Also fails to run
   record.get(field.getFieldPath());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use getSObject ?

Comment: and what is 'record'? which type this variable has?

Comment: @Patlatus record is an SObject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access with `getFieldPath()` should work for you, I'm surprised you're saying it doesn't compile?

The problems occur when the fieldset contains items from referenced records (dots in fieldPath). You need to use something similar to [Using sObject.get() to fetch a field value from a related parent object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24801/using-sobject-get-to-fetch-a-field-value-from-a-related-parent-object)

```
sObject acc = [SELECT Owner.Manager.Profile.Name 
    FROM Account WHERE Owner.Manager.Profile.Name != null LIMIT 1];
String path = 'Owner.Manager.Profile.Name';

// refactor this bit into helper function
List<String> tempPath = path.split('\\.');
Sobject temp = acc;

if(tempPath.size() > 1){
    for(Integer i = 0; i < tempPath.size() - 1; ++i){
        String currentLevel = tempPath[i];
        System.debug(currentLevel);
        temp = temp.getSobject(currentLevel);
    }
}
String last = tempPath[tempPath.size()-1];
System.debug(last + ': ' + temp.get(last));
```

You'll still have to add null checks ;) Or at least some try-catch.