# Not able to fetch reference field data in SOQL

Tags: soql, reference

Here is my query:

```
List<object1__c> lstRecords = [SELECT field1__c, field2__r.Name FROM Object1__c];
populateData((List<sObject>)lstRecords);

//I need to pass sObject, since this function would be used for multiple objects
public void populateData(List<sObject> lstRecords){
    System.debug(lstRecords[0].get(field1__c))         //This works fine
    System.debug(lstRecords[0].get(field2__r.Name))    //This does not work
}
```

The query debug shows following:

```
Object1__c:{field1__c=data}    //I don't see the field
```

Any solution for the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
System.debug(lstRecords[0].getSobject('field2__r').get('Name'));
```

Because `get()` method in `sObject` class doesn't support reference field retrival. Relationship name to be used instead of field Name in the getSobject method.

You can refer [this Stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24801/using-sobject-get-to-fetch-a-field-value-from-a-related-parent-object) question for more information and the various get methods available for the [SObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @KeithC for adding the reference to SObject class. I was about to add that.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem is Salesforce Sobject method `get` retrieves you the information from a record if it is a well formed column/field in the object.

Try using this in your second debug

```
getSobject('ParentRelationshipName');

List<Sobject> lstRecords = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name FROM Contact Where AccountId !=null Limit 1];
System.debug(lstRecords[0].get('AccountId'));         
System.debug(lstRecords[0].getSobject('Account'));
```

> 18:42:57.035 (35456209)|EXECUTION_STARTED
>   18:42:57.035 (35488472)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
>   18:42:57.046 (46363313)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|00190000010kcO0AAI
>   18:42:57.046 (46522790)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|Account:{Id=00190000010kcO0AAI, Name=Acc1}
>   18:42:57.046 (46597800)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
>   18:42:57.047 (47922463)|EXECUTION_FINISHED