# Invalid field error when querying a parent record's field

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

This is my SOQL query

```
List<BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c> bogQueryList = [
    SELECT 
        BOG_Committee__r.Name, 
        BOG_Committee__r.Official_1__r.Name, 
        BOG_Committee__r.Role_1__c, 
        BOG_Membership__r.ORG__c, 
        Member_Type__c,
        BOG_Membership__r.Contact__r.Name, 
        BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Membership_Status__c  
    FROM BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c 
    WHERE BOG_Committee__r.Name = 'Executive'
    AND BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Membership_Status__c = 'Active'
    AND BOG_Membership__r.RecordTypeID = '012w0000000MNtO'];
```

I get:

> Invalid field BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Membership_Status__c for BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c

when I do this

```
for(BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c record :bogQueryList) 
{ 
    if ((String) record.get('BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Membership_Status__c') <> Null)
```

How to get that value from the result set? 
Also, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you please update your question with all the relevant code?  We can't see how the `record` variable is declared or intialised, so it's currently impossible to provide you with an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sObject.get() to fetch a field value from a related parent object](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24801/using-sobject-get-to-fetch-a-field-value-from-a-related-parent-object)

Comment: I updated it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get it by just using the following:

> record.BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Membership_Status__c

i.e.

```
if(record.BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Membership_Status__c != null)
{
    .. do stuff ..
}
```

The reason the `record.get('BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Membership_Status__c')` doesn't work is because you need to use `getSobject()` to get the parent record when using the dynamic syntax.

Using the `.get('fieldname')` is a dynamic syntax.

i.e. you could have a variable defining which field to retrieve:

```
String myFieldName = '.. appropriate field name ..';

if(record.get(myFieldName) != null)
{   ..  do stuff .. }
```

If you wanted to use a dynamic field, you'd need to get the parent SObject first.  For more information on this, see: [Using sObject.get() to fetch a field value from a related parent object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24801/using-sobject-get-to-fetch-a-field-value-from-a-related-parent-object)

Comment: Please explain this. When I replaced record.get('BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Membership_Status__c') with record.BOG_Membership__r.BOG_Membership_Status__c the error went away. When to use each of them?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b See updated answer for more information.  Specifically, that link has some great info in it.